# DEV 401 suspended.why?

Tags: certification

I sat for the DEV 401 certification,due to technical issues i couldn't complete the test.The test got suspended and it says to contact the program manager for information on rescheduling the exam.

I opened a case and yet to get a reply from them. Is there anything else I should do? How long does it take to get the rescheduled date.

Comment: They provide contact number as well. You should call him

Comment: There's little the community can do to answer this, only salesforce certification support can guide on this.

Answer (score 1):

Shell Black has a really great [blog](http://www.shellblack.com/training-and-certification/salesforce-certified-app-builder/) post explaining what has happened with the different Developer Certifications but in short the Dev 401 will be retired in the next few days. The first paragraph here explains what is happening to the Dev 401 and how it is being changed:

> On June 18th, 2015 Salesforce sent an email to existing Salesforce
>   Certified Developers letting them know that a beta program was being
>   put together for a new certification – Salesforce Certified App
>   Builder. Just as the Salesforce Consultant certification morphed into
>   two new certifications back in 2011 (Sales Could Consultant and
>   Service Cloud Consultant), the Developer track was being split into a
>   declarative "button click" App Builder certification and a true
>   programmatic "coder" track with two new certifications supporting that
>   path: Salesforce Certified Platform Developer I and Salesforce
>   Certified Platform Developer II. In that email, to help with the
>   confusion, Salesforce published an [App Builder Certification FAQ](http://certification.force.com/pkb/articles/Public_KB/FAQ-New-App-Builder-and-Platform-Developer-Credentials).

Although not directly related, it might be the reason you haven't heard back yet. Since they will no longer be offering this exam, they may have you take the app builder exam instead. If there is a number to call I would definitely call otherwise try the success community [Salesforce Training and Certification](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000001oFf) group and/or reply to the case email you received and request an update on the case status.

Comment: I think her question was why the exam was suspended once started. I think it's up to the developer to migrate to app builder or keep renewing the 401.

Comment: @cartman yup I totally misread the question.

Comment: Updated with other channels for getting answers.